# Run-time Cost of Coproduct?

Tags: scala, shapeless

After reading [Solving Problems in a Generic Way using Shapeless](http://www.cakesolutions.net/teamblogs/solving-problems-in-a-generic-way-using-shapeless)'s first sentence of the conclusion:

> In this article, I've demonstrated how generic solutions can be created for ADTs without relying on an expensive runtime feature such as reflection

Does that mean that Shapeless's coproducts do **not** use run-time reflection or casting, contrary to [ADTs](http://typelevel.org/blog/2014/11/10/why_is_adt_pattern_matching_allowed.html) in Scala?

Comment: Neither use runtime reflection. Didn't read the article (yet), but knowing Shapeless and its Coproduct, I will guess that what is meant as an alternative encoding for the kind of generic implementation that Shapeless makes possible would be by using reflection.

Comment: Perhaps I should've said, `no runtime casting like ADTs`?

Comment: That would a different question :) But I think Shapeless doesn't either.

Comment: So, I read the article, i find the quoted paragraph quite ambiguous.

Comment: I think https://twitter.com/lepovirta/status/760013462277881856 clears it up.

Comment: Back to my first comment. Shall we point him to this question anyways?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm the author of the blog post. I think there's been a misunderstanding: I didn't mean to imply that the ADTs rely on runtime reflection. What I was referring to was this sentence from the introduction:

> Traditionally, generic programs have been written with the help of reflection APIs.

As far as I know, ADTs don't use runtime reflection, but without shapeless, there's not a lot of choices for traversing an ADT in a generic way. One way to achieve this is to use reflection for [looking up object fields at runtime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getFields--) and iterating through the fields. You could also write code that traverses through your ADT and pattern matches on every ADT node, but that solution will only work for your ADT and not for all of the other ADTs, i.e. the solutions is would not be generic.

Comment: Hopefully this answer clears things up. I'll gladly answer any questions regarding the blog post.